# Speeding up repeated calls to `ParametricNDSolve`

Tags: differential-equations, performance-tuning

I am running a Markov-chain Monte Carlo sampling code.  Evaluating the objective function for this case requires solving a system of ODEs for a large number (≈500) of different values of a parameter that appears in the ODEs.  This is taking up a lot of processing time.  Using `ParametricNDSolve` has given me some speed-up relative to calling `NDSolve` multiple times, but is there another technique that might be able to give results more quickly (perhaps at the expense of some accuracy)?

As a toy example, you can consider the ODE $x'' + x' + a^2 x = 0$ with initial conditions $x(0) = 1$ and $x'(0) = 0$.  We want to find $x(1)$ for various values of $a$.

```
avalues = RandomReal[{0, 10}, 500];
tvalue = 1;
```

(This is a simplified example;  the real system of ODEs can't be solved exactly.)  The brute-force method would be

```
AbsoluteTiming[
 bruteforceresult[a_] := 
  Module[{aval = a}, 
   soln = NDSolve[{x''[t] + x'[t] + a^2 x[t] == 0, x[0] == 1, x'[0] == 0}, x, {t, 0, tvalue}];
   x[tvalue] /. First[soln]
   ];
 bruteforceresult /@ avalues;
 ]

(* {0.233394, Null} *)
```

However, we can speed things up by using `ParametricNDSolve`:

```
AbsoluteTiming[
 parsolution = 
  ParametricNDSolve[{x''[t] + x'[t] + a^2 x[t] == 0, x[0] == 1, x'[0] == 0}, x, {t, 0, tvalue}, a];
 parresults = (x[#][tvalue] /. parsolution) & /@ avalues;
 ]

(* {0.104657, Null} *)
```

Are there any other ways to speed up this evaluation?

Comment: Have you tried [`ParametricNDSolveValue`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ParametricNDSolveValue.html)? Something like `ParametricNDSolveValue[{x''[t] + x'[t] + a^2 x[t] == 0, x[0] == 1, x'[0] == 0}, x[1], {t, 0, 1}, a]` should get you $x(1)$ as a function of $a$.

Comment: @Roman:  That does appear to speed things up a little (10-20%), though not as much as the PDE technique described in my answer.

Comment: Speed improvements depend on the details of ODE and the number of cases.  `Parallelize` can help a lot, if each computation is slow (which is not the case here).  Sometimes the `ParametricNDSolveValue` option `Method -> {"ParametricSensitivity" -> None}`. makes a significant difference, especially for highly nonlinear ODEs.

Comment: @bbgodfrey:  Yeah, I'm already planning to run the Markov chains on parallel kernels (at least after the initial burn-in.)  Thanks for the tip about the `"ParametricSensitivity"` option.

Answer (score 4):

For some parametric ODE problems (including this one), one can recast the problem as a PDE which happens to not involve any derivatives with respect to one of the variables.  Generating a sampling of ODE solutions and interpolating between them (which is effectively what `NDSolve` does when it uses the method of lines) can be much quicker than calculating an ODE solution for each individual value of the parameter:

```
AbsoluteTiming[
 pdesolution = 
  NDSolve[{D[x[t, a], {t, 2}] + D[x[t, a], t] + a^2 x[t, a] == 0, 
    x[0, a] == 1, (D[x[t, a], t] /. t -> 0) == 0}, 
   x, {t, 0, tvalue}, {a, 0, 10}];
 pderesults = (x[tvalue, #] /. First[pdesolution]) & /@ avalues;
 ]

(* {0.017581, Null} *)
```

However, this does come at the expense of accuracy.  We can get exact results for this ODE:

```
exactsolution = 
 DSolve[{D[x[t, a], {t, 2}] + D[x[t, a], t] + a^2 x[t, a] == 0, 
   x[0, a] == 1, (D[x[t, a], t] /. t -> 0) == 0}, x, {t, a}];
exactresults = (x[tvalue, #] & /@ avalues) /. First[exactsolution];
```

And we can compare the two sets of numerical results to these exact results:

```
ListLogPlot[{Transpose[{avalues, Abs[parresults - exactresults]}], 
             Transpose[{avalues, Abs[pderesults - exactresults]}]}]
```

[image]

We can see that the results from the PDE technique are much less accurate, though they may still be acceptable in some circumstances.  The PDE results can be made more accurate by tweaking the minimum number of points in the `PDEDiscretization` options:

```
  Method -> {"PDEDiscretization" -> {"MethodOfLines", "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"TensorProductGrid", "MinPoints" -> 100}}}]
```

Increasing the number of PDE grid points does slow the code down somewhat, but it may still be quicker than applying `ParametricNDSolve`.

Comment: Simpler to use NDSolveValue and to rely on listability: `sol = NDSolveValue[{Derivative[2, 0][x][t, a] + 
     Derivative[1, 0][x][t, a] + a^2 x[t, a] == 0, x[0, a] == 1, 
   Derivative[1, 0][x][0, a] == 0}, x, {t, 0, 1}, {a, 0, 10}]` and `sol[tvalue, avalues]`

Answer (score 1):

This vectorized version runs a little slower for me:

```
AbsoluteTiming[
 sol = NDSolve[{x''[t] + x'[t] == -avalues^2.x[t],
   x[0] == Table[1, 500], x'[0] == Table[0, 500]}, x, {t, 0, tvalue}][[1]];
 x[tvalue] /. sol;
]
(* {0.02996, Null} *)
```

compared to your PDE approach, which gives me `{0.019783, Null}`.  At first I thought this helped, but repeated runs showed otherwise.

Note that my initial attempt

```
sol = NDSolve[{x''[t] + x'[t] + avalues^2. x[t] == 0, 
  x[0] == Table[1, 500], x'[0] == Table[0, 500]}, x, {t, 0, tvalue}][[1]];
```

didn't work at all.  I guess you have to be careful setting these up!